# Android, pausing and resuming handler callbacks

Tags: android, callback, handler

I have a handler that I am using as follows:

```
handler.postDelayed(Play, 1000);
```

when my application onPause() is called before this is done, I need to pause it and tell it not to perform the "postDelayed" until I resume.

is this possible, or is there an alternative way?

My problem is that when onPause() is called I pause the audio (SoundManager), but if this handler.postDelayed is called after that, the audio will not be paused and will continue to play with my application in the background.

```
@Override
public void onPause()
{
  Soundmanager.autoPause()
}
```

but then the postDelayed after 1000ms starts the audio playing again.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you tried with:

```
@Override
public void onPause()
{
  handler.removeCallbacks(Play);
  Soundmanager.autoPause()
}
```

Ger

Comment: Yes, but if I resume this, the sound that the callback was removed for never started playing so there is nothing to resume. I still want it to resume that sound. (Or start it if it hasn't already started).

Comment: You can implement the onResume method and execute there the handler.postDelayed(Play, 1000);

Comment: This was a long time ago, and I have significant Android experience since this question. I'll accept this answer because it is correct in that I should remove the callback when pausing.

Answer (score 20):

You need to subclass `Handler` and implement pause/resume methods as follows (then just call `handler.pause()` when you want to pause message handling, and call `handler.resume()` when you want to restart it):

```
class MyHandler extends Handler {
    Stack<Message> s = new Stack<Message>();
    boolean is_paused = false;

    public synchronized void pause() {
        is_paused = true;
    }

    public synchronized void resume() {
        is_paused = false;
        while (!s.empty()) {
            sendMessageAtFrontOfQueue(s.pop());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if (is_paused) {
            s.push(Message.obtain(msg));
            return;
        }else{
               super.handleMessage(msg);
               // otherwise handle message as normal
               // ...
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: There is no run method. A handler is not a separate thread (it runs within your thread).

Comment: To anyone viewing this page, use this instead of the accepted answer. awesomeness

Comment: A great solution. Should be the accepted answer. It's the best way to achieve this functionality I've seen till now.

Comment: @CpnCrunch does this work for `post(runnable)` as well?

Comment: Ok, so instead of cancelling the thread in onPause, this makes the handler restart only if the time runs out before resuming.

Comment: Yes, it work for post(runnable) as well, but when i implement dispatchmessage too. But, if order is important you need change Stack to FIFO.

Answer (score 5):

Modifying the answer given by [CpcCrunch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1192732/cpncrunch). There **handleMessage** not worked for me, so instead of it using **dispatchMessage**. Note: Below code is written in Kotlin:

```
class CustomHandler: Handler() {

    var s = Stack<Message>()
    var is_paused = false

    @Synchronized
    fun pause() {
        is_paused = true
    }

    @Synchronized
    fun resume() {
        is_paused = false
        while (!s.empty()) {
            sendMessageAtFrontOfQueue(s.pop())
        }
    }

    override fun dispatchMessage(msg: Message?) {
        if (is_paused) {
            s.push(Message.obtain(msg))
            return
        } else {
            super.dispatchMessage(msg)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solved it for me after hours of frusturation. I don't know why I didn't scroll slightly down to see this in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static boolean handlerflag=false;
    private Handler handler;
    private Runnable runnable;
    private int myind=0,index=0,count=0;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_activtiy);         
        //oncreate exe only
        handlerflag=true;
        handler = new Handler();
        startyourtime(0);
 }
  private void  startyourtime(int a) {

    myind=0;
    for (index=a; index<10 ;index++) {
            myind++;
            runnable=new Runnable() {
                count++;
                @Override
                public void run() {
                          //your code here
               }
            };handler.postDelayed(runnable, Constants.TIME_LIMIT * myind);

   }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        handlerflag=false;
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(!handlerflag)
        {
           startyourtime(count);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with an alternative to [CpnCrunch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1192732/cpncrunch) when wanting to pause/resume `Runnables` in a queue. To have methods that has been called whilst still connecting and is offline, once online, resume the queue and all runnables are executed.

Instead of using `Handler`, use `ExecutorService`:

```
public class ExecutorQueueService extends ThreadPoolExecutor {
    private Stack<Runnable> runnables = new Stack<>();
    private boolean paused = false;

    public ExecutorQueueService() {
        super(1, 1, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
    }

    public synchronized void pause() {
        paused = true;
    }

    public synchronized void resume() {
        paused = false;
        while (!runnables.empty()) {
            execute(runnables.pop());
        }
    }

    public synchronized boolean isPaused() {
        return paused;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(Runnable runnable) {
        if (paused) {
            runnables.push(runnable);
        } else {
            super.execute(runnable);
        }
    }
}
```

Using it is similar to Handler, but instead of `post(runnable)`, use `execute(runnable)`