# Display Score In A Different Way in a Game

Tags: android

I am making a game and would like  To display the score in such a fashion that if my score is 0 and is increased by 10, then the score should increment through all of the numbers from 0 to 10. After reaching the new score it should stop, for at least a small pause.

If, again, the score is increased by another 10, the scoreboard should increment through every number from 10 to 20 and then stop again.

I have tried using handlers but unsuccessful in getting them a pause or stop, in any way.

The example in this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NdZ8YupmEmA&feature=fvwrel) demonstrates what I am trying to accomplish. If you look at the scoreboard in the top right, you will see the score constantly incrementing. Here is the url in case the above link does not work: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NdZ8YupmEmA&feature=fvwrel

This is the code for my Runnable to increment the score.

```
final Handler mHandler=new Handler();
    mRunnable=new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            String s = null;
                   ++i;
                   s= new Integer(i).toString();    
                   tv.setText(s);
                   mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable,1000);       

                }

        /*protected void onStop() {
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
        }*/
    };

    mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable,1000);
```

What I specifically need is how to get the code to stop counting.

Comment: This is totally unclear.

Comment: here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NdZ8YupmEmA&feature=fvwrel
look at the score board

Comment: I don't know what I'm supposed to be seeing; it just looks like an incrementing number.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth The OP wants to print all the numbers between two score intervals,say 0 to 10. So the OP wants to print all numbers from 0 to 10,ie,1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10,and all of them should be displayed.

Comment: @GursahibSahni take a look at this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/4428898/828625

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply print all the numbers between 2 end points.
Say:

```
int counter = 0;
while(counter%10 != 0)
{
textView.setText(counter.toString());
counter++;
}
```

And then again continue with the loop, just start with 11 this time,not 0.

I'm not sure it'll work as you want, like in your Temple Run example. I would want to add a little `sleep()` of very small amount, but yesterday I was advised not use `sleep()` method in Android development.

EDIT:

Ok. [This tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20200810154212/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/using-handler-in-android.html) seems pretty easy to handle. You can apply the same logic to your score display mechanism using `Handler`(as you probably guessed).

Comment: @GursahibSahni If this answer worked for you, you should vote it up and accept it.