# Cancel handler.postdelayed from another activity in which it was not created

Tags: android, handler, android-handler

Mind the typos, just a mock up.

```
class myActivity1 extends Activity
{
 oncreate()
  {
    Handler myHandler = new Handler();
    myHandler.postDelayed(myRunnable,1000)
  }

 onPause()
  {
  }
}
```

The handler does its job, and after 1 second the myRunnable runs. Assuming I call another postDelayed inside my myRunnable, that restarts the postDelayed for repetition.

In myActivity1 I am not using the removeCallbacks() function, thus the myHandler will be running even if I leave the activity.

However, my question is, HOW CAN I CANCEL the myHandler from inside another activity that I moved to ? (Assume my app has 15 activites, and I do not know inside which one I am.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Singelton class like :-

```
public class MyHandler {
    private static Handler handler;

    public static Handler getHandler() {
        if (handler == null) {
            initHandler();
        }
        return handler;
    }

    private static void initHandler() {
        handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(myRunnable,1000);
    }

    public static void stopMyHandler() {
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    }

    public static void pauseMyHandler(Runnable myRunnable) {
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(myRunnable);
    }

    public static void resumeMyHandler(Runnable myRunnable) {
        handler.postDelayed(myRunnable,1000);
    }
}
```

Use `MyHandler.getHandler()` to run it and `MyHandler.stopMyHandler()` to stop it in any activity.

In your `Activity` class:-

```
    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        MyHandler.pauseMyHandler(myRunnable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        MyHandler.resumeMyHandler(myRunnable);
    }
```

Code for `Runnable` that runs on UI thread:-

```
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

          @Override
          public void run() {
                //update your UI
          }
    });
```

Comment: whenever I use stopMyHandler when the user has pressed the home button for example, what is the best strategy to have it continue inside onResume() when the user reenters the activity ? I am planning on using a boolean value has stopped and switch it on and off and check it inside every onResume() of my app.

Comment: i guess your answer is in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428860/android-pausing-and-resuming-handler-callbacks)

Comment: thanks, regarding if I want to change the UI from the thread thats running the singleton. is it possible ?

Comment: **yes**, but it depends on `Runnable` code. You should place `runOnUiThread(myRunnable);` in your implementation of `run()`.

Comment: thanks @mrsus, can you update the code if possible ? thanks a hunch.