# When is run() called when you post a Runnable to a Handler?

Tags: android, runnable, android-handler

I want to `post()` some `Runnable`'s to a `Handler` I have created and run some code before and after the `run()` of the `Runnable` is called. Is there any easy way to do this by overriding the `Handler` class or similar?

Edit: I am using the pause method in the answer on this page: [Android, pausing and resuming handler callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9726030/2668136). Basically I want to inject a pause whenever the handler starts to run a `Runnable` (or `Message`) and then resume the handler externally.

Comment: Perhaps you can share the codes you've written?

Comment: @HaydenKai use AsyncTask

Comment: so as can you see in the answer you posted its `void handleMessage(Message msg)` where `Message`s are handled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @pskink mentioned the `Runnable` is called here,

```
@Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    if (isPaused) {
        stack.push(Message.obtain(msg));
    } else {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
    }
}
```

The `Runnable` that is posted is turned into a `Message` and then the `Message` is handled here.