# determination of user inactivity android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, timer

I have a small application Image Slider. There is a scrolling timer for the picture. The timer does not stop if the user is active and scans the images manually. How to pause the timer for the user and resume it in the event that the activity has stopped. Help me please. I'm just starting to study iandroid studio/

MainActivity.java

```
package com.androidtutorialpoint.androidimageslider;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static ViewPager mPager;
    private static int currentPage = 0;
    private static final Integer[] XMEN= {R.drawable.beast,R.drawable.charles,R.drawable.magneto,R.drawable.mystique,R.drawable.wolverine};
    private ArrayList<Integer> XMENArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        init();
    }
    private void init() {
        for(int i=0;i<XMEN.length;i++)
            XMENArray.add(XMEN[i]);

        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this,XMENArray));
        CircleIndicator indicator = (CircleIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        indicator.setViewPager(mPager);

        // Auto start of viewpager
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final Runnable Update = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (currentPage == XMEN.length) {
                    currentPage = 0;
                }
                mPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);
            }
        };
        Timer swipeTimer = new Timer();
        swipeTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(Update);
            }
        }, 2500, 3000);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pause the handler in the activity onPause lifecycle callback. There's an example located here: [Android, pausing and resuming handler callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428860/android-pausing-and-resuming-handler-callbacks/9726030?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

You can then resume the timer in the activity onResume() lifecycle callback.

Comment: thanks for the your answer. as far as I understood from the example, there was a pause and a resume. Can I track the user's gestures and only then make pause? In advance I apologize for the my silly questions. I do not quite understand how to arrange it yet.

Comment: Ah, in that case use gesture detection instead of the Activity lifecycle callbacks as your start and stop. Check out gesture detection here: https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html

Comment: how it will be looks like in the code? main code need to wrap up in onTouchEvent smile then if returns "true" play a pause?