# Resume after pausing program with handler.postDelayed

Tags: android

I am a newbie in android studio. I am having trouble resuming a program
after pausing it with several handler post delays.

The program runs and the handler does its thing but if I press the sleep button on my Samsung phone while the program is still active
the program pauses but when I return to the program the program doesn't resume. The program still pauses where it stopped when I pressed the sleep
button.

I have several handlers in the same fragment.

How can I resume the program where it stopped?

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

        do something

            }
        }, 5000);
```

and so on............

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428860/android-pausing-and-resuming-handler-callbacks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android, pausing and resuming handler callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428860/android-pausing-and-resuming-handler-callbacks)