# Resuming Runnable() making application error

Tags: android, handler, runnable

I have a `Handler()` that needs to pause when device is locked. I've used the code `removeCallBacks(runnable)` but after resuming, I call again `handler.post(runnable)` but the app crashes. How can I do it?. this is the codes

```
 //globally
 Handler handler = new Handler();

private final Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Open RF Card interface
        validateCardValue();

        handler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 2000);
    }
};



//onPause()
   @Override
public void onPause() {
    handler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
    super.onPause();
}

//onResume()
 @Override
public void onResume() {
    Log.e("resume!","resume");
    try{
        handler.post(mRunnable);
    }catch (Throwable e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    super.onResume();
}
```

Comment: remove  final from Runnable

Comment: it didn't work.

Comment: if crash, do you have an Exception? and stack trace?

Comment: can you post Logcat error

Comment: For me this code is working fine, maybe you're facing error somewhere else

Comment: You can try subclassing Handler to handle pause and resume in a more efficient manner as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9726030/1273550).

Comment: can you try moving super.onResume to top of the method.

Comment: @AIMINPAN  No stacktrace on logcat. thats the weirdest thing of it

Comment: @ali No stacktrace on logcat. thats the weirdest thing of it

Comment: I have tried to add some breakpoints but app still crashes without stacktrace. please help :3

Comment: where you are using this code ? in Activity or Fragment ?

Comment: I have tested this code working perfectly fine for activity, Pausing and Resuming perfectly.

Comment: @AliAhmed on fragment mate

Comment: Working fine in Fragment too . i think there might be some other problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182243/discussion-between-ali-ahmed-and-mike-gorospe).